# Is it possible to get ls to show file size, not allocated size?

Tags: command-line, ls

When downloading a large file, there is a big discrepancy beween the actual file size (which I care about) and the allocated (ie, final) size (which I usually don't.)

```
$ ls -lshk
9962420 -rw-r--r--  1 stevebennett  staff    19G 16 Jan 14:30 parcelsclip.zip_.gstmp
```

In this case, the file will be 19GB eventually, but right now, it's only 9.96GB, as indicated by the first column.

Is there a way to have that 19G column show the current size (9962420), but in human-friendly terms (10GB)?

Comment: What software are you using to download that 19 GB file?  Many download managers create a temporary file that will have the ongoing, current size, even though they allocate the full file space (yes, that is duplicate allocation for the time the download takes to transfer and verify).

Comment: It's gsutil. Yes, I get that the space is allocated - but you can see in the left column that the currently consumed part of that space is also available, so that's what I'd like to see - just in human-readable mode.

Comment: Ah, I see.  You want something that works like this invocation of `ls` but shows the 9962420 as something like "10.0 G".  Nope, don't know how to do that, but clarifying what you're after improves the chances someone else will.

Comment: That number (the final size of a download) is unavailable to the client. After all, the connection could drop. The download  client increases file size (allocates more local disk space) for each buffer it receives.

Comment: Use `du -h filename` ("du" stands for "disk usage") instead of `ls`.

Comment: @egmont Oh, I'll pay that. Want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `du -h filename` instead of `ls`.

"du" stands for "disk usage", and although usually used for directories, it also reports for single files the amount of disk space they actually occupy.

`-h` makes it report human readable numbers, e.g. "10.0G".